# bootstrap 3 responsive desgin

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, browser

I am interest to learn how we can remove a portion of the page content when the page width is a below a certain size? Here is an example of page content with Bootstrap three being removed and added based on browser width.

http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#examples

As you can see, the left selector column is viewable for large screen sizes and is removed for smaller screen sizes.

Thanks.

Comment: The left menu isn't removed, it gets pushed to the top of the page (before the content proper).

Answer (score 0):

You can hide an element using some of the provided classes, such us:

- visible-desktop
- visible-tablet
- visible-phone
- hidden-desktop
- hidden-tablet
- hidden-phone

they are set in the responsive bootstrap css under @media types.
Take a look at http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html#responsive

Comment: EDIT: On bootstrap 3 they are now call visible-sm,visible-md, visible-lg, hidden-sm, hidden-md, hidden-lg.

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate the help with the question. These were clear answers.

Answer (score 0):

Check [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html#responsive) website, Responsive utility classes